# Property 'focus' does not exist on 'Element'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Creating a keyboard navigation, and facing the following issue:

```
let currentActive = document.activeElement;
if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
  currentActive.previousElementSibling.focus();
}
```

The code works as expected, but TypeScript complains that `Property 'focus' does not exist on 'Element'?` - the `currentActive` is an `<img />` tag.

I've tried assigning the currentActive to be a HTMLElement, by doing so:
`let currentActive = document.activeElement as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`, but it doesn't seem to like that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convince TS that `currentActive.previousElementSibling` is of type `HTMLElement`.

As a bonus tip I would recommend to convince yourself as well avoiding some red crosses in your console. Maybe something along the lines of `currentActive?.previousElementSibling?.focus?.();`

Comment: `focus?.()` should be `.focus()`. The edit que is full otherwise i would edit the answer.

Comment: I'm not so sure, `previousElementSibling` returns an Element and not all elements have the focus method.

Comment: Yup. I can confirm that this solution does not work for elements such as `mat-checkbox`

Answer (score 46):

I would suggest trying something like this:

```
let currentActive = document.activeElement;
if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
  (currentActive.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement)?.focus();
}
```

Note that optional chaining is available since TypeScript 3.7

Comment: Great solution! Unfortunately running an older version of TS :(

Comment: But why's this happening? Doesn't TS know that its not an HTMLElement?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and I solved it by defining the type of the element I was expecting from `queryselector`. In my case I was expecting an `input` element, so I did:

```
document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(`input[name=${element-name}]`)?.focus()
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `as` to tell TS its a HTMLElement:

```
(currentActive.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement).focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (el instanceof HTMLElement) { el.focus()}
```

or in your case:

```
const htmlElement = currentActive.previousElementSibling

if (htmlElement instanceof HTMLElement) { htmlElement.focus()}
```